# Add quotes around sentences with the word "said"

Tags: python, regex, text

Ok regex masters, I have a very long text and I'm trying to add quotes in sentences that contain the words "he said" and similar variations.

For example:

```
s = 'This should have no quotes. This one should he said. But this one should not. Neither should this. But this one should she said.'
```

Should result in:

```
This should have no quotes. "This one should," he said. But this one should not. Neither should this. "But this one should," she said.
```

So far I can get pretty close, but not quite right:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.sub(r'\.\W(.*?) (he|she|it) said.', r'. "\1," \2 said.', s)
```

Results in:

```
>>> print m
This should have no quotes. "This one should," he said. But this one should not. "Neither should this. But this one should," she said.
```

As you can see, it puts quote properly around the first instance, but places it too early for the second. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This seems more like a natural language processing problem, rather than a simple regex problem. Unless the sentences you are quoting are always in a predefined format.

Comment: Don't care so much about catching _all_ instances of pronouns, etc. My issue (at the moment) is getting the quotes in the right places.

Comment: What will you do with sentences like `"He said this would be hard."`?  No quotes are needed there since it isn't a direct quote.

Comment: I'm hoping to adapt my working regex to get those instances in a separate pass. Bonus points to anyone who can catch both in one regex, but I think it's probably not possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different valid situations that have been pointed out in the comments, but to address the concern you were facing:

It is quoting the whole sentence because it sees the period at the end of `one should not.`. What you really want, is to only quote back to the *last* period. So in your matching brackets make sure to not include periods, like so:

```
m = re.sub(r'\.\W([^\.]*?) (he|she|it) said.', r'. "\1," \2 said.', s)
```

This will fail for things with periods in the sentence like `"Dr. Seuss likes to eat, she said"` but that is another problem.

Comment: ...and in under the 4-minute to allow approval mark, this works great! The `^` is what looks back to a period and space?

Comment: @JeffThompson - No.  `[^\.]` is saying "any character that isn't a period".

Comment: @JeffThompson yeah, what iCodez said. Glad it works! Had a quick break at work, nothing better than looking at regex on your break...